# How to convert server based database to local database(MDF to SDF) C#?

Tags: sql-server, file, sql-server-ce

Windows application in C# cannot connect to database without SQL Server installed. I created a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio (2013) using C#, for customers info. I created the database with SQL Server and then imported to Visual Studio with data sources.

But it's not working without SQL Server installed. Maybe I need some sort of `.MDF` to `.SDF` conversion, but do not need a server database just local database is required.

Comment: If you cannot install SQL Server on the client's machine, then using SQL Server Compact Edition with a `.sdf` file is one of several alternatives. You just need to use SQL Server CE (`.sdf`) right from the beginning, in your coding - there's no easy `MDF-to-SDF` conversion path - just use SQL Server CE in your development and deploy everything to any machine, without any additional installations needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox to move schema and data from SQL Server to SQL Server Compact